# Двойной запрос на сервер с клиента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

Отправляю запрос на сервер с клиента через библиотеку axios.

Запрос отправляется вроде как один раз, но в логах сервера, на сервер поступает 2 запроса,
подумал может проблема в сервере, но при запросе на тот же эндпоинт, в логах сервера уже приходит 1 запрос.

Логи сервера при запросе с клиента:

```
info: webapi.Middlewares.LogMiddleware[0]
  { user = { username = air, id = 1, role = HighestAdmin }, request = { path = /api/core/users/1, method = GET } }
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (40ms) [Parameters=[@__userId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']      SELECT u.id, u.email, u.password_hash, u.role, u.username, t.file_id, t0.key_id, t0.person_internal_key, t0.private_key, t0.received_internal_key, t0.user_id, t.file_mime, t.file_name, t.operation_date, t.type, t.user_id
  FROM users AS u
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT f.file_id, f.file_mime, f.file_name, f.operation_date, f.type, f.user_id
      FROM files AS f
      WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM keys AS k
          WHERE u.id = k.user_id AND k.user_id = f.user_id)
  ) AS t ON TRUE
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT k0.key_id, k0.person_internal_key, k0.private_key, k0.received_internal_key, k0.user_id
      FROM keys AS k0
      WHERE u.id = k0.user_id
  ) AS t0 ON TRUE
  WHERE u.id = @__userId_0
  ORDER BY u.id, t.file_id
info: webapi.Middlewares.LogMiddleware[0]
  Status Code: 200

info: webapi.Middlewares.LogMiddleware[0]
  { user = { username = air, id = 1, role = HighestAdmin }, request = { path = /api/core/users/1, method = GET } }
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__userId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT u.id, u.email, u.password_hash, u.role, u.username, t.file_id, t0.key_id, t0.person_internal_key, t0.private_key, t0.received_internal_key, t0.user_id, t.file_mime, t.file_name, t.operation_date, t.type, t.user_id
  FROM users AS u
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT f.file_id, f.file_mime, f.file_name, f.operation_date, f.type, f.user_id
      FROM files AS f
      WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM keys AS k
          WHERE u.id = k.user_id AND k.user_id = f.user_id)
  ) AS t ON TRUE
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT k0.key_id, k0.person_internal_key, k0.private_key, k0.received_internal_key, k0.user_id
      FROM keys AS k0
      WHERE u.id = k0.user_id
  ) AS t0 ON TRUE
  WHERE u.id = @__userId_0
  ORDER BY u.id, t.file_id
info: webapi.Middlewares.LogMiddleware[0]
  Status Code: 200
```

А вот уже лог сервера при запросе с POSTMAN:

```
info: webapi.Middlewares.LogMiddleware[0]
  { user = { username = air, id = 1, role = HighestAdmin }, request = { path = /api/core/users/1, method = GET } }
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (39ms) [Parameters=[@__userId_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT u.id, u.email, u.password_hash, u.role, u.username, t.file_id, t0.key_id, t0.person_internal_key, t0.private_key, t0.received_internal_key, t0.user_id, t.file_mime, t.file_name, t.operation_date, t.type, t.user_id
  FROM users AS u
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT f.file_id, f.file_mime, f.file_name, f.operation_date, f.type, f.user_id
      FROM files AS f
      WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM keys AS k
          WHERE u.id = k.user_id AND k.user_id = f.user_id)
  ) AS t ON TRUE
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT k0.key_id, k0.person_internal_key, k0.private_key, k0.received_internal_key, k0.user_id
      FROM keys AS k0
      WHERE u.id = k0.user_id
  ) AS t0 ON TRUE
  WHERE u.id = @__userId_0
  ORDER BY u.id, t.file_id
info: webapi.Middlewares.LogMiddleware[0]
  Status Code: 200
```

Эндпоинт один, но почему запроса то два.

Вот код запроса на сервер с клиента:

```
import Interceptor from './AxiosRequestInterceptor';

const BASE_URL = 'https://localhost:7067/';

const AxiosRequest = async ({ endpoint, method, withCookie, requestBody }: RequestProps) => {
    try {
        var response;

        switch (method) {
            case 'POST':
                response = await Interceptor.post(`${BASE_URL + endpoint}`, requestBody, { withCredentials: withCookie });
                break;
            case 'GET':
                response = await Interceptor.get(`${BASE_URL + endpoint}`, { withCredentials: withCookie });
                break;
            case 'PUT':
                response = await Interceptor.put(`${BASE_URL + endpoint}`, requestBody, { withCredentials: withCookie });
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                response = await Interceptor.delete(`${BASE_URL + endpoint}`, { withCredentials: withCookie });
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error('Invalid request method');
        }

        return { isSuccess: true, data: response.data };

    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error);
        let errorMessage = 'An error occurred during the request';
        if (error.response) {
            errorMessage = error.response.data && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : 'Unknown error';
        }

        return { isSuccess: false, data: errorMessage };
    }
}

export default AxiosRequest;
```

Код интерцептора:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import cookie from 'react-cookies'

const Interceptor = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://localhost:7067' });
Interceptor.interceptors.request.use(request => requestInterceptor(request))

const requestInterceptor = (request: any) => {
    request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = cookie.load('.AspNetCore.Xsrf')
    return request;
}

export default Interceptor;
```

Вот так сам вызывется функция для запроса на сервер:

```
const { userId } = useParams();
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
const [successStatusCode, setStatusCode] = useState(false)
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

const fetchData = async () => {

    const response = await AxiosRequest({ endpoint: `api/core/users/${userId}`, method: 'GET', withCookie: true, requestBody: null })

    if (response.isSuccess) {
        setUserData(response.data);
        setStatusCode(true);
    }
    else {
        setErrorMessage(response.data);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [userId]);
```

Comment: В useEffect добавьте `console.log(userId)` и посмотрите, что происходит. Подозреваю, что userID меняется. Ну и вкладка network консоли разработчика в помощь, там видно, что и сколько отправляется

Comment: @SwaD userId изменяется с 1 на 1. Я в react новичок, и не слишком хорошо понимаю что тут вообще происходит. Можете подсказать что мне с этим делать ? P.S немного дополнил код

Comment: А ну и еще, наверное важное дополнение, перехожу по страницам через изменение URL, ибо интерфейса пока что немного

Comment: UseEffect срабатывает каждый раз на изменение переменных в массиве зависимостей. Т.е. у вас на каждое изменение userId будет отправляться запрос.

Comment: А я еще предположу, что у вас включен `StrictMode`, он вызывает дважды `useEffect`.

Comment: один запрос OPTIONS, а второй уже с тем методом который вы указали?)

Comment: @OliverPatterson Да и правда все было из-за StrictMode, после отключения запрос стал отправляться единожды, То что из-за StrictMode, useEffect может отрабатывать дважды на SO я не нашел. Так что укажите это в ответе, я отмечу его как принятый. Вам баллы репутации, а сообществу новые ответы на вопросы).

Comment: @air2921, вам нужно просто почитать документацию по `StrictMode`

Comment: @OliverPatterson Просто я даже не мог подозревать, что это могло быть из-за StrictMode. Он стоял в шаблоне react приложения по умолчанию, так что не думал что это может быть из-за того что поставляется "из коробки".